# Tableau: How to show two measures from different data sources in the same chart (without blending)

Tags: tableau-api

Currently I have a chart that displays monthly GA visitors. This data comes from a GA table in the DB (Table 1)

I have a separate data source for purchases (Table 2). I have a chart that shows # of monthly purchases, but I'd like to combine these into one chart so I can show a monthly conversion rate.

Tableau keeps prompting me to blend data and I don't want to do that (I don't think). Tableau seems really unintuitive at times.

Please see the screenshot below. The numbers in red are what I'm looking for. They need to pulled on the same dates as the GA data. I can derive the conversion % from there.

Thank you! Tried a bunch of stuff but getting nowhere.

[image]

Comment: you can't show unrelated data on the same chart.  Why don't you want to blend?

Comment: The only way Tableau can know which numbers to plot for each date is if there is a date common to both sources. Blending is how Tableau knows about this connection. So you will have to blend (by telling Tableau the date fields are linked) and there should not be any other problem caused by this. You **do** want to do that and there is no good reason not to.